# How can I call a modal from another component using Angular Bootstrap?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples), and basically generating a button to call a modal in `app.component.ts`, and I am also assigning 2 parameters to be displayed dynamically in the modal.

```
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Hello, {{name}}!  {{lastname}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open('jhon','doe')">Launch demo modal</button>
```

My ideal is to put this functionality within a provider `(ServicesProvider)`, and in the style of:

```
fn_callModal(name:any,lastname:any){
 this.ServicesProvider.fn_callModal(name,lastname);
}
```

[image]

To be able to invoke the modal in any section, for example in `home.component.ts`. I don't know how to do to call the modal in a different component to `app.component.ts`

```
app.component.html

<router-outlet class="m-0 p-0" ></router-outlet>
<ngbd-modal-component></ngbd-modal-component>
```

This is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-modal-content-jsbsyb?file=app/home.component.ts

Comment: OK. How does the NgbdModalComponent do to open the modal? Just copy that code into your fn_callModal() method, and voilà.

Comment: Note that what you're calling a provider is not a *provider*. It's a *service*.

Comment: @JBNizet works! Is my code the best way? by the way, I always believed that a service was the same as a provider

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "the best way". The main problem in your code is the lack of respect for naming conventions, and goof naming in general. Classes should be in `CamelCase`. Variables, methods and function in `camelCase`. `fn_callModal` doesn't say much about what it does, and uses a useless `fn_` prefix. How about naming it `openGreetingModal()`?

Comment: Regarding services and providers. A provider is what allows providing the service to Angular. `{ provide: FooService, useClass: MyFooService }` is a provider for example. Its role is to let Angular know how to get or create an instance of the service `FooService`. The command to generate a service is `ng generate service`, not `ng generate provider`.